# Как сделать, чтобы значения в словаре добавлялись с изменением значения переменной? // Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, переменные, словарь

У меня есть переменные **keys** и **value**.
Их значения *постоянно меняются*, я хочу сделать, чтобы в словарь заносились значения этих переменных(keys будет ключом, value значением). Но когда значения этих переменных поменялись, прошлые значения остались в словаре, а новые занеслись, и так каждый раз, когда переменным присваивались новые значения.
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Вариантов много, например каждому новому key, ставить значение key, key_1, key_2. Или использовать массив с указанием [{key=x,value=1},{key=x,value=2}] и.т.д.  Или {key=[value],anotherKey=[value1,value2]}

Comment: можно код пожалуйста первого способа)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
keys = {}
database = {}

def add(key, value):
    if key in keys:
        keys[key] += 1
        database[key + "_" + str(keys[key])] = value
    else:
        database[key] = value
        keys[key] = 0

def get_latest(key):
    if key in keys:
        if keys[key] == 0:
            return database[key]
        else:
            return database[key + "_" + str(keys[key])]
    return None

add("hello", "world")
add("hello", "univerce")
add("hello", "another world")

print(keys)
print(database)

print("latest hello = ", get_latest("hello"))
```